# Bot Channel Registration did Move to other Resource group

Tags: azure, botframework

I had created a Bot using Bot framework and integrated it with MS Teams.I had to move my entire resource group to another subscription.I performed the migration using the "MOVE" option availble on Azure portal.I see the old resource group is now empty but in the new resource group I cant find Bot Channel Registration object.

Comment: Have you already created a support ticket in Azure?

Comment: Can you look in all resources and filter by bot service? I also know that sometimes it takes a bit of time for things to show up. If you still have problems, please open a ticket as @mick suggested.